# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XX error occurring randomly for a application deployed on glassfish

Tags: glassfish-3, java-7, noclassdeffounderror

We have an application deployed on glassfish V3.1.X. The application performs an ETL operation which involves reading records from excel files and loading them into a database table.

Sometimes the application code fails with an NoClassDefFoundError. Strange thing is that the application works on restart

The last two failures were for two different classes:

First exception was:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorkbookDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source) ~[poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar:3.9]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader$SheetIterator.<init>(XSSFReader.java:207) ~[poi-ooxml-3.9.jar:3.9]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader$SheetIterator.<init>(XSSFReader.java:166) ~[poi-ooxml-3.9.jar:3.9]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.getSheetsData(XSSFReader.java:160) ~[poi-ooxml-3.9.jar:3.9]
at com.etlapplication.readexternalfile.excel.model.POIWorkbookImpl.getSheetNames(POIWorkbookImpl.java:368)
```

And second one was:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread
at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:117) ~[lucene-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1 1461071 - mark - 2013-03-26 08:28:27]
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:145) ~[lucene-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1 1461071 - mark - 2013-03-26 08:28:27]
at com.etlapplication.readexternalfile.excel.model.IndexedSharedStringTable.<init>(IndexedSharedStringTable.java:73)
```

I didn't find any ExceptionInInitializerError in logs that could point towards some static initialization issues.

I have already enabled logging of the class loading messages to see from where the class is getting loaded, but everything seems to be fine for now. Waiting for the issue to occur again, to see if class is getting loaded from some different place.

Any suggestions to further troubleshoot the issue.